# Angular js select does not work when css class applied

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am using angular js to populate a select component like this

```
select ng-model="search.year" ng-options="year for year in years"
```

When I add a CSS class, `class="select_5"` it no longer works. I tried using `ng-class` instead of class, in which case the component works but the css style is not being applied. Any ideas?

Comment: It would help to see some examples of the actual code you've tried. Also mind the formatting.

Comment: Please edit your post with html, css and js.